# HaxeFlixel - Expected } error when using a case command

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

I keep getting an error where it's expecting a } in the "case 'captain-cool'" I don't know what it means and adding a } gives me the same error.

```
swith(curSong.toLowerCase());
        {
            case 'captain-cool':
            {
                trace('matthewanimation')
                inCutscene = true;

                var matthewMicGrab:FlxSprite = new FlxSprite();
                var micsound:FlxSound = new FlxSound().loadEmbedded('assets/week1/sounds/micsound.ogg')
                var armmove:FlxSound = new FlxSound().loadEmbedded('assets/week1/sounds/armmove.ogg')
                matthewMicGrab.frames = Paths.getSparrowAtlas('assets/week1/images/cutsceneshit/matthewMic.png','assets/week1/images/cutsceneshit/matthewMic.xml');
                matthewMicGrab.animation.addByPrefix('micgrab', 'Matthew MIC', 24, false);
                animation.antialiasing = true;
                add(animation);
```

Comment: Error is specifically "Playstate.hx:830: characters 4-8 : Expected }"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need braces after a `case` statement, and `switch` is not a function.

This is a demonstration of the correct syntax:

```
switch (curSong.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'captain-cool':
        trace('matthewanimation');
    case 'something-else':
        doStuff();
    default:
        doDefaultThings();
}
```